# "Maximal" sets with cardinality $\aleph_0$?

Tags: set-theory

I have this very rough and probably wrong intuition that the set of rational numbers is "more dense" than the integers, because the set of rational numbers is dense in itself whereas the set of integers isn't. I'm wondering if there is a name or anything for this notion of "jumping" from a not-dense-in-itself set to a dense-in-itself set with the same cardinality? i.e., is there a generalization of this to sets with cardinality $\aleph_1$? Are there sets with cardinality $\aleph_1$ that are "more dense" than other sets in $\aleph_1$? Or some similar notion? Thanks!

Comment: Few comments and questions: 1. What do you mean by being dense in itself? Dense in its own subspace topology? In this sense every set is dense in itself. 2. Denseness is a topological property. Saying that $\mathbb{Q}$ is more dense or less dense doesn't make sense: it either is dense (in some superset) or it isn't.

Comment: I'm not so sure it doesn't make sense to say that a set is more dense than another: if $A$ were dense in a greater cardinality of "obvious" superspaces (for some appropriate definition of obvious, if possible) than $B$ was, I wouldn't hesitate to call $A$ more dense. But generically considering sets across all sets of cardinality $\aleph_1$ would probably not give a nice notion of obvious.

Comment: There is a defined notion of [dense-in-itself](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Dense-in-itself), namely that a topological space $T$ contains no isolated points.  In just this sense $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense-in-itself (while the integers are not).  However AFAIK this doesn't lead to a generalized notion of one "set" being more dense than another.

Comment: If your use of "dense-in-itself" agrees with the definition given by hardmath, the Cantor set is an example of a dense-in-itself subset of the line with the cardinality of the continuum. Whether or not this equals $\aleph_1 $ of course is independent of ZFC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look up Hausdorff dimension. Sets of reals that have the same cardinality can have different Hausdorff dimensions, which can sorta kinda be seen as a notion of density.

Comment: However, the Hausdorff dimension of a countable set is zero so it cannot help for countable sets. In the same idea, there are upper and lower Minkowski dimensions (aka box dimensions), working at least for some countable sets.